# Lucene.NET indexing one-letter words?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, indexing

I'm using Lucene.NET, when I try to index for example the following text: "In de **categorie T** zijn tijdelijke borden (zwarte tekst/symbolen op gele achtergrond) opgenomen die niet in permanente uitvoering beschikbaar zijn."

It is going about the text in bold, all thing are indexed quite wel, but one the T will be ignored.

Does someone knows this problem/issue. I'm using the following syntax.

```
doc.Add(new Field("text", text, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"T" is a stop word by default in standard analyzer. You can provide your own stop-word list when creating an analyzer.

Just create an analyzer like this:

```
StandardAnalyzer standardAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(new string[]{"an", "a", /*other stopwords*/});
```

And use it during indexation and search.

Comment: I use the StandardAnalyzer, and I use the tool Luke to check if the T is in the index. I do a exact word combination search for "categorie T" and nothing is found.

Comment: @wsplinter, please check the solution above.